# I am unable to install modules in Python on OSX

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am a beginner and am trying to install some modules in Python on OSX. I want to install SymPy.

One site says that I should run this in Terminal:

```
pip3 install SymPy
```

I ran it and I got this:

```
Aaryans-Macbook:~ apple$ pip3 install SymPy
Requirement already satisfied: SymPy in ./anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.0)
Aaryans-Macbook:~ apple$
```

If I run Python in my Terminal and try importing SymPy, it works!

However, in my IDLE (where I write code), if I try to import it, I get this error:

```
import sympy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File '<pyshell#0>', line 1, in <module>
    import sympy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
```

I have tried every `sudo` command in my Terminal but nothing worked.

I know this is very basic stuff but given the beginner, I am please, help me.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that SymPy already exists in your system. Your IDE might be using some other location of python installation

Comment: @skaul05 How do I know what location is it using and how do I change it!?

Comment: Which IDE are you using

Comment: If you installed the module with `pip3`, you should run `idle3`. `idle` is going to run Python version 2 and it will not use modules you installed for Python 3.

Comment: @skaul05 Check this out: https://imgur.com/a/JHHZzDh

Comment: @Bert I installed idle 3.7.2 and I am getting this error: https://imgur.com/a/8SBWKHP

Comment: It's more helpful to copy/paste the text in the windows than to post a screenshot of them. It also helps to show what command you used to start IDLE etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first screenshot, SymPy is installed using Anaconda, and in the second screenshot you are not running the IDLE that is included with Anaconda. Therefore it is not configured to locate the modules you installed.

On macOS, the full path may be `/Users/jsmith/miniconda3/bin/idle3.5`

*(replace `jsmith` with your username)*

You can confirm the different paths that Python is searching for by running this code:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Execute those lines in both the Python you run from the command line, and the IDLE you run from the command line and you will see that they are different.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible due to your path settings. See some examples of other peoples issues here
[How to add to the pythonpath in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows)

Although the best thing is if when you install Python and select add Python to environment variables during the anaconda installation - but a quick workaround could be (specially for Mac)

http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/28/set-enviornment-variables-mac-os-x/

```
nano ~/ .bash_profile
```

then when your bash_profile opens, check your environment variables that you have

```
export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```